# File search between two dates with ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a way to do a file search between two dates and I'm searching for a method to make this **more beautiful than my example below** , I specify that this example code below works

I know the ansible `find` module exists  but I can't perform a search between two dates like I want to implement in my example (or at least I didn't succeed)

1. file search between the 2022-09-26 and the 2022-10-26
2. create some files for the test `touch -d "35 days ago" /tmp/toto /tmp/tata /tmp/tutu.zip`
3. run the playbook

```yaml
- name: "test find"
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  hosts: "localhost"
  tasks:
  - name: "create vars"
    set_fact:
      path_to_find:             "/tmp"
      BEGIN_DATE:               "{{lookup('pipe','date -d \"2 months ago\" -I')}}"
      END_DATE:                 "{{lookup('pipe','date -d \"1 months ago\" -I')}}"
      ZIP_NAME:                 "archive_test_name.zip"

  - name: "find between two dates "
    shell: find "{{ path_to_find }}" -type f ! -name "*.zip" -newermt "{{ BEGIN_DATE }}" ! -newermt "{{ END_DATE }}"
    register: FindFiles

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ FindFiles }}"
```

I hope someone has an idea or a best practice !

Comment: Hi Yanis welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74575954/edit) and include what that code snippet **is** doing for you, because the ways it _can_ fail are infinite, but the ways it _is_ failing are finite and known only to you. Good luck

Comment: Not related to your direct problem but why declaring those vars in `set_fact` when you just have to put them in the play `vars` section (which saves a task execution...)

Comment: And please review @mdaniel comment above and [edit] your question with more details because as far as I am concernced, [your above example is giving the exact expected result](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/5e0cd6e9f1fbab8c0418ebeb47bb1449)

Comment: Hi,
The purpose of my question was to find a way to do my example using the ansible `find` module like the answer below.

Comment: This is much clearer with your latest edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the files for testing

```bash
shell> ls -ogla /tmp/test/
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  2  4096 Nov 25 21:23 .
drwxrwxrwt 70 20480 Nov 25 22:28 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Jul 25 00:00 file1
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Aug 25 00:00 file2
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Sep 25 00:00 file3
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Oct 25 00:00 file4
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Nov 25 00:00 file5
```

1. Find lists of files older than the dates and create the difference between these lists.

In addition to the declarations

```yaml
  begin_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d \"2 months ago\" -I') }}"
  end_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d \"1 months ago\" -I') }}"
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  today: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime }}"
  begin_days: "{{ ((today|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) -
                   (begin_date|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days }}"
  end_days: "{{ ((today|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) -
                 (end_date|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days }}"
```

gives the date of today and the number of days from *begin_date* and *end_date*

```yaml
  begin_date: 2022-09-25
  end_date: 2022-10-25
  today: 2022-11-25
  begin_days: 61
  end_days: 31
```

Find and register files where the modification time is older than *begin_date*  and *end_date*

```yaml
    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
        age: "{{ begin_days }}d"
      register: begin

    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
        age: "{{ end_days }}d"
      register: end
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  begin_files: "{{ begin.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
  end_files: "{{ end.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
  my_files: "{{ end_files|difference(begin_files) }}"
```

gives the lists of files where the modification time is older than *begin_date* and *end_date*. The difference between these lists *my_files* is what you're looking for

```yaml
  begin_files: ['/tmp/test/file3', '/tmp/test/file2', '/tmp/test/file1']
  end_files: ['/tmp/test/file3', '/tmp/test/file4', '/tmp/test/file2', '/tmp/test/file1']
  my_files: ['/tmp/test/file4']
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    today: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime }}"
    begin_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d \"2 months ago\" -I') }}"
    end_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d \"1 months ago\" -I') }}"
    begin_days: "{{ ((today|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) -
                     (begin_date|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days }}"
    end_days: "{{ ((today|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) -
                   (end_date|to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days }}"
    begin_files: "{{ begin.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
    end_files: "{{ end.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
    my_files: "{{ end_files|difference(begin_files) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          today: {{ today }}
          begin_date: {{ begin_date }}
          end_date: {{ end_date }}
          begin_days: {{ begin_days }}
          end_days: {{ end_days }}

    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
        age: "{{ begin_days }}d"
      register: begin

    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
        age: "{{ end_days }}d"
      register: end

    - debug:
        msg: |
          begin_files: {{ begin_files }}
          end_files: {{ end_files }}
          my_files: {{ my_files }}
```

---

2. Collect the status of the files and select files by time.

Change the format of the dates to seconds

```yaml
  begin_date_cmd: "date -d '2 months ago' '+%s'"
  begin_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', begin_date_cmd) }}"
  end_date_cmd: "date -d '1 months ago' '+%s'"
  end_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', end_date_cmd) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  begin_date: 1664143922
  end_date: 1666735922
```

Declare the variable

```yaml
  files_all: "{{ all.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

and get the list of all files

```yaml
    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
      register: all
```

Collect the status of all files

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      register: st
      loop: "{{ files_all }}"
```

Declare the list where the modification time is bigger than begin_date and less than end_date

```yaml
  my_files: "{{ st.results|selectattr('stat.mtime', 'gt', begin_date|float)|
                           selectattr('stat.mtime', 'lt', end_date|float)|
                           map(attribute='item')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_files:
  - /tmp/test/file4
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    begin_date_cmd: "date -d '2 months ago' '+%s'"
    begin_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', begin_date_cmd) }}"
    end_date_cmd: "date -d '1 months ago' '+%s'"
    end_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', end_date_cmd) }}"
    files_all: "{{ all.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
    my_files: "{{ st.results|selectattr('stat.mtime', 'gt', begin_date|float)|
                             selectattr('stat.mtime', 'lt', end_date|float)|
                             map(attribute='item')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          begin_date: {{ begin_date }}
          end_date: {{ end_date }}

    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
      register: all
    - debug:
        var: files_all

    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      register: st
      loop: "{{ files_all }}"
    - debug:
        var: st
      
    - debug:
        var: my_files
```

Comment: Hello my friend,
That's great, thank you for the answer and the work provided.
If no one has an easier solution, this answers the question

Comment: @Yanis The "Don't use shell when an ansible module exists" mantra should be obeyed whenever possible but should not be taken too literally either. In your particular case (respecting Vladimir's as usual perfectly on-spot answer), the solution given in your question and that you're trying to refactor is easy, maintainable and performant. As is, the `find` module does not allow to give several dates anyway (i.e. `ages` expect a single intrger). Hence you're using shell to workaround a module limitation. That's really a case where it looks OK.

Comment: JFYI. There are [differences in the implementations of *find*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238738/find-files-newer-than-15-seconds-but-older-than-2-seconds).

Answer (score 2):

> ***I'm searching for a method to make this more beautiful***

Depending on your infrastructure and other capabilities there might be an other approach possible, creating a Custom Module written in Bash or Shell as a wrapper for the specific `find` command.

By doing this one will prevent multiple lookup's on the Control Node as well multiple find or searches on Remote Nodes since the approach will result into a single task. Furthermore, there will be much less configuration description within the Ansible playbook YAML and even less variable declaration, Jinja2 templating, filtering and setting facts.

The following concept / example module takes some string parameters (`path`, `begin`, `end`). After it is providing the files found as a list.

**Concept / Example Module** `between.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

exec 3>&1 4>&2 > /dev/null 2>&1

# Create functions

function return_json() {

    exec 1>&3 2>&4

    jq --null-input --monochrome-output \
       --arg changed "$changed" \
       --arg rc "$rc" \
       --arg stdout "$stdout" \
       --arg stderr "$stderr" \
       --arg files "$files" \
       '$ARGS.named'

    exec 3>&1 4>&2 > /dev/null 2>&1

}

# Set default values

changed="false"
rc=0
stdout=""
stderr=""
files="[]"

source "$1" # to read the tmp file and source the parameters given by Ansible

# Check prerequisites

if ! which jq &>/dev/null; then
    exec 1>&3 2>&4
    printf "{ \"changed\": \"$changed\",
           \"rc\": \"1\" ,
           \"stdout\": \"\",
           \"stderr\": \"Command not found: This module require 'jq' installed on the target host. Exiting ...\",
           \"files\": \"[]\"}"
    exit 127
fi

if ! grep -q "Red Hat Enterprise Linux" /etc/redhat-release; then
    stderr="Operation not supported: Red Hat Enterprise Linux not found. Exiting ..."
    rc=95

    return_json

    exit $rc
fi

# Validate parameter key and value

if [ -z "$path" ]; then
    stderr="Invalid argument: Parameter path is not provided. Exiting ..."
    rc=22

    return_json

    exit $rc
fi

if [[ $path == *['!:*']* ]]; then
    stderr="Invalid argument: Value path contains invalid characters. Exiting ..."
    rc=22

    return_json

    exit $rc
fi

if [ ${#path} -ge 127 ]; then
    stderr="Argument too long: Value path has too many characters. Exiting ..."
    rc=7

    return_json

    exit $rc
fi

# Main (logic part)

    if [ -d "$path" ]; then
        files=$(find $path -type f -name "file*" -newermt "$begin" ! -newermt "$end" | jq --raw-input . | jq --slurp .)
    else
        stderr="Cannot access: No such directory or Permission denied."
        rc=1
    fi

# Return

changed="false"

return_json

exit $rc
```

**Test Playbook** `between.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get files between
    between:
      path: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/files"
      begin: "3 month ago"
      end: "1 month ago"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result.files
```

Executed on a test file set

```bash
ls -ogla /home/${ANSIBLE_USER}/files
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 4096 Nov 29 11:41 .
drwx------. 37 4096 Nov 29 14:04 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1    0 Jul 29 12:43 file1.zip
-rw-r--r--.  1    0 Aug 29 12:44 file2.zip
-rw-r--r--.  1    0 Sep 29 12:44 file3.zip
-rw-r--r--.  1    0 Oct 29 12:44 file4.zip
-rw-r--r--.  1    0 Nov 29 11:41 file5.zip
```

and via `sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user ${ANSIBLE_USER} --ask-pass between.yml`

**Result**

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ***********
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result.files:
  - /home/user/files/file4.zip
  - /home/user/files/file3.zip
```

Please take note that within the current example the filenames are hardcoded (`-name "file*"`). I'll leave the enhancement of this part to the reader.

**Thanks and Credits to**

For script and module

- [Ansible: Need generic solution to find size of folder/directory or file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73687567/6771046)
- [How to execute a shell script on a Remote Server using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363872/6771046)
- [Create A Simple Custom Module Using Bash Script In Ansible](https://technekey.com/ansible-custom-module-using-bash-script/)

and very important

- [Ansible Common Return Vaules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

For general Linux and Shell

- [Verify the length of a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145159/266568)
- [What are the standard error codes in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326811/266568)
- [Filename length limits on linux?](https://serverfault.com/a/9548/448950)
- [What characters should be restricted from a Unix file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34193591/6771046)
- [How to check if a string contains a special character (!@#$%^&*()_+)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26621800/6771046)
- [Converting lines to JSON in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603242/6771046)